# Typescript import and Webpack

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, umd, hellosign-api

I am trying to use the [hellosign-embedded](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hellosign-embedded) module from my TypeScript application, which is then packaged using Webpack and run as part of a web page.

I've also imported the [`@types` typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/hellosign-embedded).

The problem is that if I use:

```
import * as HelloSign from "hellosign-embedded";
```

Typescript gives me an error:

```
error TS2306: File 'D:/Work/ProjectX/node_modules/@types/hellosign-embedded/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

I've also tried simply using:

```
import "hellosign-embedded";
```

Which gives me access to the `HelloSign` global from my code, but the problem then is that after running webpack, when running it in the browser, `HelloSign` is not found:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: HelloSign is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (onboarding.tsx:10)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3570)
    at process (jquery.js:3638)
```

What's the proper way to import this library? Is there a problem with the typings provided?

Answer (score 0):

do this it works for me :

```
   import HelloSign = require("hellosign-embedded");

   console.log(HelloSign.init);
```

go to the definition file : `node_modules/@types/hellosign-embedded/index.d.ts`

add this to the end of file :

```
export = HelloSign;
```